# Weird memory corruption when calling external C library in Python wrapper

Tags: python, c, debugging, cython, memory-corruption

I have some Cython code, which is actually a wrapper for an external C library as explained in the relevant documentation and several other sources (e.g.[here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) and [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html)). I have the following Cython class definition:

```
import numpy
cimport numpy
cimport clib # my C library

cdef class DoStuff:
    def __call__(self, array a):
        cdef numpy.ndarray[float, ndim=1] npa = numpy.ascontiguousarray(a)
        clib.cStuff( <float*>npa.data )
```

My C function (`cStuff`) always behaves as expected when compiled and run in other C code, and its return values are completely determined by the input (no random number generation involved). It allocates float arrays in the heap using `malloc()`, and never `free()`s, as both C and Python code terminate the execution after `cStuff` has finished. However, when I call the function from within Python sometimes (like 1 out of 5) memory corruption takes place and `cStuff` returns meaningless results, as if the memory allocated by the C program was overwritten. The array a is not corrupt when the C function is called, because correct values are printed by `cStuff` in any case. Any idea of what could cause this?
Thank you

Comment: It's easily possible that your C library either (a) doesn't allocate enough memory, but in your C program it always gets lucky, or (b) stomps on the stack, but in your C program there's so little left to do after returning from `cStuff` that everything works out anyway. So, just because it "behaves as expected" doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: Also, you can look at the code generated by Cython and compare what it's doing to your C program and see if there are any obvious differences.

Comment: I get this exact problem too. I'm working in C++. I allocate an array using `new` within my library. Then I put data into it. In Cython, I copy the data to a numpy array. Then I call a library function that deallocates my array.  Most of the time it works just fine, but sometimes, I get semi-nonsense. It's super-weird because what I'm actually doing is creating a histogram. So some characteristics of the histogram are sometimes left... but sometimes not... It's easy to see in the final image that corruption of some sort has happened, but it hasn't totally washed out my array.

Comment: None of this is deterministic. Sometimes there's just noise. Sometimes there's a mix of the histogram and noise. Could it be that Cython doesn't like memory allocated by libraries??

Answer (score 3):

I cannot infer from the code where your issue is. I would need more context.

Have you tried running this under Valgrind?

http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck

Run it like this:

`> valgrind python script.py`

Comment: Normally, something like this would be better as a comment than as an answer. But in this case, it seems like it would be a very long, and much harder to read, comment, so maybe this is the best alternative.